# Limit not getting applied to ElasticSearch query - using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement server side pagination through ElasticSearch query in my Rails ap using the from and size parameter options.

The version of elasticsearch gem I am using is 2.0 and also the Elasticsearch server version is 2.0

But the query always returns the total results and not applying the limits specified. When using the same query in Postman it returns the correct limit of records specified.

Does this have anything to do with the ruby gem or server versions?
Or am I doing something wrong here?

```
  query = {
   "from" => 0, "size" => 100,
    "query" => {
      "bool" => {
        "filter" => {
          "terms" => {
            "group_id" => grouparray
          }
        }              
      }
    }
  }
end
data = client.search index: index ,search_type: 'scan', scroll:'1m',  body: query.to_json 
results = Array.new
info = Hash.new
info["size"] = 0      
while data = client.scroll(scroll_id: data['_scroll_id'], scroll: '1m') and not data["hits"]["hits"].empty? do     
  info["size"] = info["size"] + data["hits"]["hits"].size
  data["hits"]["hits"].each do |hit|
    h = Hash.new
    h["report_date"] = hit["_source"]["report_date"]
    h["name"] = hit["_source"]["name"]
     results.push(h)
  end         
end      
return {:stats => info, :data => results}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using scroll query. It will always go through all items. You can remove "search_type: 'scan'" and it will return only chunk specified.